# Objective-C, Having trouble properly inheriting ivars to subclasses and methods

Tags: objective-c, oop, methods, subclass, superclass

**First Question here**, I've searched around and I am afraid I don't know the exact terminology for what I am trying to do - please don't attack me if it's already been asked. Point me in the right direction and I'll read up.

I have Class:
"Shape" (Of NSObject)
Subclasses of "Shape" include:
"circle" etc - each with their respective calcArea(calculate area) methods.

My subclasses work great as individuals getting class "Circle" to set the ivars(using "Shape" methods in "Shape" and inherit them, then calculate area using those.

What I want to do:
I want to be able to set the parameters for a "Shape" object. I then want these parameters to trickle down to each of the subclasses ("Circle", "Triangle", etc) so that I can enter two parameters and it gives me all my area and circumference calculations from each subclass. Each of the subclass methods ARE the same "calcArea" for example.

---

Theories:
-Brute forcing my way through using 2 variables in my main method to reset each parameter for each subclass. **this seems really inefficient, but works.**
-using "id", basically make this object create parameters in "Shape" through each subclass then looping through each subclass until all were finished. Tried a couple of things, can't figure it out.
-creating an object in "Shape" that then performs each of the functions of its subclasses - this sounds bad from what I've read, superclasses shouldn't know about what their subclasses do... can I create a method in "Shape" that performs [myCircle calcArea] and [myTriangle calcArea]?
-I'm designing this program wrong.

---

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly. In OOP subclasses inherit all attributes of their superclasses. So when you have:

```
@interface Shape : NSObject {
     int _mParam;
}
-(int) calcArea;
@end
```

you can actually access _mParam in your subclasses. Then create the subclass:

```
@interface Circle : Shape {
}
-(id) init:(int) param;
-(int) calcArea;
@end

-(id) init:(int) param {
    ....
    _mParam = param;
    ....
}

-(int) calcArea {
    //some calculations here
    return M_PI*r*r + _mParam;
}
```

Comment: so If I'm understanding you correctly, I can create the method in the SuperClass then have actually define and initiate it in the superclasses. - That makes perfect sense to me, but how does the id work in this instance?
It appears to be initiating the class with "param" as the variable correct?  How should that be coded in the main function though?

Comment: id is the pointer to the object's internal structure. You should not worry about id at all - it is used internally by the runtime system.

Comment: ok, I won't worry about id.

I mean in my actual program:
    Shape *s = [[Shape alloc]init];
    [s setWidthHeight:5:10];
    [s ....];

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll read up and if I have any more questions I'll come back but I think I've got a sincere understanding of the processes here.  I sincerely appreciate your patience.